# expresso Store: notify admin when an user make an order or payment

Tags: expresso-store, email, notification

Is it possible with store to send an email to an admin , or another member, or maybe an email, when the user make an order or a payment?

mx notify control doesn't support store

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an order is placed, any email triggered by the default order status will be sent.

For example, if your default order status is "New", and you have an "Order Confirmation" email template set up, and your email template is assigned to the "New" status, it will get sent when each order is placed (this is set up when you first install Store).

Currently you can only send one email per status - but you can easily BCC the store admin so they know an order has been placed.

Comment: can i add multiple emails with comma in BCC?

Comment: Yes, you can add as many emails to BCC as you like.

Comment: Perfect. I've another question: when an user choice manual payment and i "capture" the payment in the details order, a confirm payment's email should be sent to the user. But i tried and it doesn't work

Comment: In that case no email will be sent by Store automatically. Sometimes your gateway would send an email to the customer. The best option is to create a new order status, and change the order to that status at the same time you capture payment.